# BigDecimal/ArrayList needs new Locale

Tags: java, arraylist, locale, bigdecimal

I have an ArrayList in which I add BigDecimals.

My problem is, that the BigDecimals use `.` and `,` the american way - and I want it the European way - e.g. instead of `14.70` I want `14,70`.

I made a method:

```
public static String getLocale(BigDecimal n) {
   String newValue      =   null;
   if (n != null) 
      newValue  =   NumberFormat.getInstance().format(n);   
   return newValue;
}
```

Wherein when I print the entire `ArrayList` to a .csv I call this method for each of the Bigdecimals. However I was wondering if I can change the entire ArrayList to know, that I want to store elements the "correct" way for me? Or maybe to change the Locale when I set the BigDecimal into the ArrayList?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is the way you've done it, although I would name the method `format()` instead of `getLocale()`, since the method doesn't get a Locale, but formats a BigDecimal.

The data is a list of BigDecimals. Whether and how this data is displayed/stored in a CSV file shouldn't change the nature of the data. If later, you need to display these data in a web page in English, you shouldn't have to change the nature of the data, but only the way this data is displayed.

Comment: Thanks a bundle! I kept the old way of doing it - even though I think I call the method way too many times...:)

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't to change the way the (BigDecimal) elements are stored!

You have to change the way they are display. You can do this with [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

For example:

```
private static final String BIG_DECIMAL_DEFAULT_FORMAT = "##0.00";
private static final char GROUPING_SEPARATOR = '.';
private static final char DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ',';
private static final int DIGIT_GROUP_NUMBER = 3;
private static final DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat(BIG_DECIMAL_DEFAULT_FORMAT);

static{
    decimalFormatter.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    decimalFormatter.setGroupingSize(DIGIT_GROUP_NUMBER);
    paschiFaceSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);
    paschiFaceSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(GROUPING_SEPARATOR);
}
```

Than you have to implement too a method to display the BigDecimal values. For example:

```
public static String format(BigDecimal value, String pattern)
{
    if (value == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error:value=null");
    }

    if (pattern != null && !pattern.isEmpty()){
        decimalFormatter.applyPattern(pattern);
    }
    else{
        decimalFormatter.applyPattern(BIG_DECIMAL_DEFAULT_FORMAT);
    }

    return decimalFormatter.format(value);
}
```